# Can we use .so file from one android ndk app to another android ndk app?

Tags: android, android-ndk

My question is that have created one android ndk project which is having its respective .so file.I want to know that can we use same .so file in another android ndk application without copying as it is from one project to another?
If yes how can we implement that?

Comment: Identical to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195426/re-use-code-android-ndk/12203975#12203975

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can if you have defined the same "native" call in the same classes in the same packages.

Answer (score 0):

Native libraries are installed in **lib** directory for an application, which is readable for anyone. Therefore, appB can use

```
System.Load("/data/data/com.appA/lib/libnativeA.so")
```

But the guess of the full path to other package's libraries is not based on documented interfaces, and there is no guarantee this will work in future versions.