# How to reuse .so file created in one android app using ndk without any change

Tags: android, android-ndk, code-reuse

I want to reuse the .so file (created by using the ndk-build in one Android App) in another android app. It seems that the JNI convention needs the class from which the native code will be called.

I got the answer of a companion jar file from the following link
[Re-use code Android NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195426/re-use-code-android-ndk/12203975#12203975)

But how to create it. Could someone elaborate it more.

Comment: You need to rewrite the JNI layer, but you can link it against the destination lib - the one the JNI wrapper lies on top of. Or, rename your package accordingly...

Comment: Yes... I guess the wrapper class is what meant by that. I created a java class file in a standard package and created a jar file. The jar file along with the armeabi->.so file was included in the libs of the new project. I now use the import statement in my app and use the instance of the wrapper class to call the native functions.